# Conditional Enablement of 'Verify' Button Based on Option Value

Tags: flutter, dart

**"I need a solution for the following:
Enable the 'verify' button only if the pinput's value matches the specified value; otherwise, keep the button disabled. How can we achieve this?"**

**Expectation: Disabled button on else condition, how can we do it? on isOTPValid false disabled "Verify" button.**

I'm using package pinput for OTP, this is my code:

```
class OTPForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleForm;

  OTPForm(this.toggleForm);

  @override
  State<OTPForm> createState() => _OTPFormState();
}

class _OTPFormState extends State<OTPForm> {
  bool isOTPValid = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [              
          Pinput(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            length: 4,
            defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
            focusedPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
              decoration: defaultPinTheme.decoration!.copyWith(
                border: Border.all(color: primaryColor),
              ),
            ),
            errorPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyBorderWith(
              border: Border.all(color: dangerColor),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              // return value == '1155' ? null : 'Pin is incorrect';
              isOTPValid = value == '1155';
              return isOTPValid ? null : 'Pin is incorrect';
            },
            hapticFeedbackType: HapticFeedbackType.lightImpact,
            onCompleted: (pin) {
              debugPrint('onCompleted: $pin');
              // widget.toggleForm();
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              debugPrint('onChanged: $value');
            },
            autofocus: true,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: mdVerticalSpacing),              
          Container(
            height: buttonHeight,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: PrimaryButton(
              text: 'Verify',
              onPressed: () {
                if (isOTPValid) {
                  widget.toggleForm();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any package like [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), the easiest way is to call `setState` for setting `isOTPValid` value. Due to `onPressed` parameter is required for the `PrimaryButton`, you can tell to user about the button's state via [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html), for example:

```
class _OTPFormState extends State<OTPForm> {
  bool isOTPValid = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [              
          Pinput(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            length: 4,
            defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
            focusedPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
              decoration: defaultPinTheme.decoration!.copyWith(
                border: Border.all(color: primaryColor),
              ),
            ),
            errorPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyBorderWith(
              border: Border.all(color: dangerColor),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              // return value == '1155' ? null : 'Pin is incorrect';
              setState(() {  //  <---------------
                 isOTPValid = value == '1155';                    
              });
              return isOTPValid ? null : 'Pin is incorrect';
            },
            hapticFeedbackType: HapticFeedbackType.lightImpact,
            onCompleted: (pin) {
              debugPrint('onCompleted: $pin');
              // widget.toggleForm();
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              debugPrint('onChanged: $value');
            },
            autofocus: true,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: mdVerticalSpacing),              
          Container(
            height: buttonHeight,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: !isOTPValid, //  <----------
              child: PrimaryButton(
              text: 'Verify',
              onPressed: () {  
                  widget.toggleForm();
              },
             ),
           ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Error: The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
bool isOTPValid
Type: bool

Comment: The reason is `onPressed` parameter is required for `PrimaryButton` and cannot be null like for `ElevatedButton`, for example. I'll update my answer in few minutes

Comment: Please try this version

Comment: Thanks, I also defined styles for the disabled button in the constructor.
isEnabled: isOTPValid,